# From std::string<char> to unsigned char[], an error "non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

There is an error message:

`non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::value_type' (aka 'char') to 'unsigned char' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]`.

The problem is treated by **MSVC** and **GCC** as warnings but **Clang** treats it as an error.

The code:

```
enum Encoding { ERR = -1, NONE, ASCII, UTF8, UTF16LE, UTF16BE, UTF32LE, UTF32BE };

Encoding CheckBOM(const std::string& data) {
    unsigned int DataSize = data.length();
    if (DataSize < 4)
        return ERR;
    // the following line is the cause of the problem
    unsigned char BOM[4] = { data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3] }; // <-- This line is what the error message points to

    if (BOM[0] == 0xef && BOM[1] == 0xbb && BOM[2] == 0xbf)
        return Encoding::UTF8;
    else if (BOM[0] == 0xff && BOM[1] == 0xfe && BOM[2] == 0x00 && BOM[3] == 0x00)
        return Encoding::UTF32LE;
    else if (BOM[0] == 0x00 && BOM[1] == 0x00 && BOM[2] == 0xfe && BOM[3] == 0xff)
        return Encoding::UTF32BE;
    else if (BOM[0] == 0xff && BOM[1] == 0xfe)
        return Encoding::UTF16LE;
    else if (BOM[0] == 0xfe && BOM[1] == 0xff)
        return Encoding::UTF16BE;
    return Encoding::NONE;
}
```

I have tried to resolve that problem but I couldn't because I don't understand it.

**How can I solve this?**

Comment: are you using `-Werror`? Can you include the whole command you are using for each compiler?

Comment: There is really no need for the `BOM` variable at all.  Just replace each use of `BOM[i]` with `data[i]` instead.  Or, use `memcmp()` instead of individual `char` comparisons, eg: `if (memcmp(data.c_str(), "\xef\xbb\xbf", 3) == 0) ... else if (memcmp(data.c_str(), "\xff\xfe\x00\x00", 4) == 0) ...`

Comment: @idclev463035818: I use Clang through VS 2019. so, I don't know which commands VS uses.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yes, you are true, but I thought that this line would simplify the code. Anyway, thank you for your tip. Regard to the comparison I think the normal `if-else` is better in performance than using the functions.

Comment: Side note: I don't think that the existence of `ERR` is justified; looks like your function should return `NONE`. Or, may be, use it if you found `FF` OR `FE` but the second character has an unexpected value.

Comment: @VladFeinstein: Thanks, I still don't understand what you mean, your talking is not clear enough.

Comment: I am saying that the string of less than 4 characters is NOT an error, it just doesn't have a BOM marker, so to me it means `NONE` in your `Encoding` enum

Comment: @VladFeinstein: That condition is just to make sure there are in the content of the file at least 4 bytes because how to implement the next conditions for example: `if (BOM[0] == 0xff && BOM[1] == 0xfe && BOM[2] == 0x00 && BOM[3] == 0x00)`  and there is less than 4 bytes? without doubt an  error will occur while runtime.

Comment: @LionKing - I understand you need to return without the BOM check in such case; I am saying that the return code is more `Encoding::NONE` then `Encoding::ERR`, as there is NO error

Comment: @VladFeinstein: Yes, I got it, you mean that is not an error. anyway thank you for your tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `std::string` is `basic_string<char>` you are assigning  a signed type `char` to `unsigned char` hence the narrowing.

Freely speaking a narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion, where the converted type cannot be represented in all cases by the target type, which is the case, converting signed to unsigned.

As the standard does not allow narrowing conversion in aggregate initialization, i.e. [braced-init-list](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#nt:braced-init-list), you must do it yourself "by hand" so to speak.

[dcl.init.aggr#4.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#4.2)

> [...] *If that initializer is of the form assignment-expression or = assignment-expression and a narrowing conversion ([[dcl.init.list]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#list)) is required to convert the expression, the program is ill-formed.*[...]

[dcl.init.list#7](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#7)

> *A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion*
>
> [...]

[list of possible implicit conversions, not needed for the matter in analysis]

> [...]
>
> ***[Note: As indicated above, such conversions are not allowed at the top level in list-initializations.
> — end note]***
>
> [Example:
>
> [...]
>
> unsigned char uc1 = {5};        // OK: no narrowing needed
>
> unsigned char uc2 = {-1};       // error: narrows
>
> unsigned int ui1 = {-1};        // error: narrows
>
> [...]

To avoid the error/warning you can to cast to `unsigned char`:

```
unsigned char BOM[4] = { static_cast<unsigned char>(data[0]), static_cast<unsigned char>(data[1]), static_cast<unsigned char>(data[2]), static_cast<unsigned char>(data[3])};
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zn5a8G)

As an alternative, as [suggested by @RemyLebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63621156/from-stdstringchar-to-unsigned-char-an-error-non-constant-expression-can/63621298?noredirect=1#comment112503922_63621298) you can use:

```
const unsigned char * pdata = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(data.c_str()); 
unsigned char BOM[4] = { pdata[0], pdata[1], pdata[2], pdata[3] };
```

Or simpler:

```
unsigned char BOM[4]; 
std::memcpy(BOM, data.c_str(), 4);
```

This one requires `#include<cstring>`.

Comment: Having to cast each individual `char` is a bit ugly. You could alternatively do this instead: `const unsigned char * pdata = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(data.c_str()); unsigned char BOM[4] = { pdata[0], pdata[1], pdata[2], pdata[3] };`  Or simpler: `unsigned char BOM[4]; memcpy(BOM, data.c_str(), 4);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau, much simpler, I added these option to the answer if you don't mind.

Comment: @anastaciu: Sorry, but what is the meaning of narrowing in that case?

Comment: @LionKing freely speaking a narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion, where the converted type cannot be represented in all cases by the target type, which is the case, converting signed to unsigned, as this conversion is not allowed, you must do it yourself "by hand" so to speak.

Comment: @LionKing, I edited the question to address this issue, the links I provided to the standard draft have more details about the matter.